# WPF Binding is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working on simple MVVM application using WPF in Visual Studio. I am providing here View code as well as Model class. My only worry is about the first Textbox which is not binding with property Name of class Form. You can skip the remaining code.
I am beginner to MVVM architecture and WPF. If you find suitable, you can suggest me mistakes as well.

Thanks.

**UI.xaml**

```
 <Window x:Class="MVVM.Views.UI"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:MVVM.ViewModels"
    Title="UI" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding MVVM.Models.Form.Name}" Margin="20,15,160,225" />


    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Back Color" Margin="20,73,195,167" />
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Font Color" Margin="20,122,195,118"/>
    <ListBox Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding notifyChangedList}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="156,42,0,143" Height="85" Width="93" />
    <Button Content="Finish" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,163,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

</Grid>
```

**Form.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace MVVM.Models
{
    public class Form : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Form()
        {

        }

        #region Variables
        private String _name;

        public String Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        private String _colorBack;

        public String ColorBack
        {
            get { return _colorBack; }
            set
            {
                _colorBack = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ColorBlack");
            }
        }
        private String _colorFont;

        public String Color_Font
        {
            get { return _colorFont; }
            set
            {
                _colorFont = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ColorFont");
            }
        } 
        #endregion

        #region INotifyPropertyChangedMembers
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        } 
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**UI.xaml.cs**

```
  using MVVM.Models;
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Windows;
  using System.Windows.Controls;
  using System.Windows.Data;
  using System.Windows.Documents;
  using System.Windows.Input;
  using System.Windows.Media;
  using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
  using System.Windows.Shapes;

  namespace MVVM.Views
  {
    public partial class UI : Window
      {
          public UI()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
              DataContext = new Form();
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Can you show code where you have assigned DataContext property

Comment: in your MVVM.Views.UI class code-behind, have you got something like `this.DataContext = new MVVM.Models.Form();`?

Comment: It sounds like you forgot to set the [DataContext](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you missed initializing DataContext property in your UI.xaml.cs.

Try initializing it in constructor

```
public UI()
{
    this.DataContext = new MVVM.Models.Form();
}
```

And in your UI.xaml, just bind text with Name property

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="20,15,160,225" />
```

UPDATE: [Added description]

DataContext is like container of "object to be binded" with UI elements and once assigned to any UI element, all the children of that UI element will also (kind of) have reference to that binding object. So in our case, assigning an object "Form" to this.DataContext is us saying UI Window that this is your object for binding, so all UI children UI elements will have a reference of this binding object. So  when we say Text = "{Binding Name}" it already know that binding object is Form and it has to look for Name property inside that object.

Code behind is actually considered as part of View and its just gluing View and ViewModel together

[image: MVVM from MSDN]

Further read

- [My Blog Posts on MVVM](http://adilmughal.com/blog/tag/mvvm/)
- [Channel9 Getting Started with MVVM](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Getting-Started-with-MVVM)
- [Using the Model-View-ViewModel Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hh821028.aspx)

UPDATE 2: [For other readers]

The answer solves the problem but it's not true implementation of MVVM. Ideally View is binded with ViewModel which may contain Model objects. Have a look at video link on Channel9 or my blog posts

Comment: It worked. Can you please explain me? I don't have much idea how this DataContext works and also why your code worked?

Comment: Also Don't you think that View shouldn't be connected directly to Model, as we did here ?

Comment: But this Data Context means you are directly connecting your View to Model, which is not proper according to MVVM architecture, Isn't it?

Comment: Yes this is not right of MVVM. Ideally you should have three elements View (including UI.xaml and UI.xaml.cs), ViewModel (say UIViewModel) and Model (Form). The UIViewModel would contain Form and its responsible for manipulating data. Go through the first or watch video in second link